# Laravel display a picture and define url from php

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

In php code i would like to define a picture that will be displayed in the blade view. Here is my code:

```
if($score_pro < 15)
    {
        $result['class'] = "success";
        $result['img'] = "thumb-green.png";
        $message_pro = "<img src='{{ url('img/".$result['img']."') }}'><br>It's ok for you";
    }
    elseif($score_pro > 14)
    {
        $result['class'] = "danger";
        $result['img'] = "thumb-red.png";
        $message_pro = "<img src=\"{{ url('img/".$result['img']."') }}\"><br>It's not ok!";
    }
```

In blade i make this:

```
<h3 class="text-muted">{!! $message_pro !!}</h3>
```

But in HTML what i have is this:

```
<img src="{{ url('img/thumb-red.png') }}">
```

I have to evaluate the img from PHP because sometime i don't have image to display.

Comment: Send your image url and $score_pro to the view. Use your logic there, and do not generate HTML elements inside your PHP code like this.

Comment: this is what I thought, but I was hoping that another solution exists

Comment: Not what I would suggest, but then don't send your html with any logic inside on your view. This means you will have to parse `url()` function on your backend and then send just a string to your view.